# Lottery with known EV and standard deviation. Probablity of positive ROI after x trials?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, expected-value, monte-carlo

Lottery with the following payout table:

```
**Payout** **Frequency**
0x             0.59992
1x             0.34992
5x             0.04982
1000x          0.00035
```

Expected value of the lottery is thus 0.95 (or 95 cents given 1$ price)

**Calculating Std.dev** = sqrt ( (0.59992 *(0 - 0.95)^2) + (0.34992 * (1-0.95)^2) + (0.04982 * (5-0.95)^2) + (0.00035 * (1000 - 0.95)^2)) =  **$18.753**

I believe the std.dev calculation above to be correct.

Now to the question

> What is the probablity to be profitable in this lottery after playing a thousand times?

Or generally:

> What is the probablity [P] to have a return >= [Y] after [X] trials?

Can we approximate the returns of the lottery to be normally distributed? I've tried to solve this problem by using binon.dist function without any luck. Perhaps a monte carlo approach would be better?

Many thanks

Comment: Hint: the answer must be  be extremely close to $1-\exp(-0.35)\approx 0.295.$  BTW, your frequencies don't sum to 1.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @whuber 

Could you please elaborate? I'm not following where you are getting the -0.35 figure from.

I've used excel solver so the frequencies do sum to 1, rounding error in the post above.

Comment: $0.35 = 1000\times 0.00035.$  The idea is that the lottery is profitable only if you win the \$1000 prize at least once or win the smaller prizes an unusually large number of times.  It turns out your chance of being profitable without ever winning the \$1000 is less than $2\times 10^{-23}$--there are various ways of obtaining simple upper bounds for this--so you really only need to consider the rare chance of winning \$1000.  The Poisson approximation is excellent; that's where the exponential formula comes from.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @whuber. Assume payout frequencies are unknown, however, expected value (average return) and standard deviation of the lottery is known. Can we generalize a formula like the following: What is the probablity [P] to have a return >= [Y] after [X] trials?